# Shiro.ini file in AEM instance

Tags: aem, ini, shiro

I had created a web app with shiro. Now i want to secure aem application with Shiro. I am not able to get where to place the `shiro.ini` file and how to set `EnvironmentLoaderListener` and `ShiroFilter`.

I had tried a lot of things like fetching ini file through `bundleContext` in `activate()` method

I want to know where i have to do the shiro configurations in aem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue,if you find any solution,please share that here.

Comment: @ShivaniGarg I had completed it and now you can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put the shiro file in resource folder and send the shiro ini file in the bundle and then fetched it from inside the bundle:

I had fetched the servlet bundleContext as:

```
@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) throws IOException {
    this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
}
```

And then used this bundleContext to fetch the url of ini file

```
URL iniURL = bundleContext.getBundle().getEntry("shiro.ini");
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.load(iniURL.openStream());
IniSecurityManagerFactory factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(ini);
securityManager = factory.getInstance();
```

This is how i got the `securityManager`.
And then used the shiro api for further login and logout purpose.